# SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, syntax

I am having an issue on my problem where the console is saying

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

and I'm not sure where it's coming from. I am a JS newbie, just learning this stuff. Would you mind pointing out where I am going wrong with my brackets please.

```
var myArray = [4, 6, 23, 10, 1, 3];

var arrayAdditon = function (arr) {
    var largestNumber = arr[0];
    var sumTotal;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
        if (arr[i] > largestNumber) {
            largestNumber = arr[i];
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
        if (largestNumber) {
            console.log(largestNumber);
        } else (arr[i] != largestNumber) {
            sumTotal += arr[i];   
        }
    }
    if (largestNumber === sumTotal) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your syntax for errors here http://www.jshint.com/

Comment: Thanks for that. I am familiar with that tool, although I am not seeing where the error is.

Comment: Well, what line is the error reported?

Comment: `else` takes no condition, it's just `else {...`

Comment: BTW, JSHint got it: _"14: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression."_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have a bug in your if...else part, try changing to this.

```
 if (largestNumber) {
     console.log(largestNumber);
 } else if (arr[i] != largestNumber) {
     sumTotal += arr[i];   
 }
```

If this doesn't work comment me the full error you got. Try to inspect it in firebug console.
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 3):

Your code updated here....

```
var myArray = [4, 6, 23, 10, 1, 3];

var arrayAdditon = function (arr) {
var largestNumber = arr[0];
var sumTotal;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
    if (arr[i] > largestNumber) {
        largestNumber = arr[i];
    }
}
for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j += 1) {
    if (largestNumber) {
        console.log(largestNumber);
    } else if (arr[i] != largestNumber) {
        sumTotal += arr[i];   
    }
}
if (largestNumber === sumTotal) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

error in syntax `else (arr[i] != largestNumber)`
put **if** there

Answer (score 1):

I can not see a missing `{`

but

```
} else (arr[i] != largestNumber) {
        sumTotal += arr[i];   
}
```

should be

```
} else if (arr[i] != largestNumber) {
        sumTotal += arr[i];   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fixed one.

```
var myArray = [4, 6, 23, 10, 1, 3];

var arrayAdditon = function (arr) {
    var largestNumber = arr[0],
        sumTotal, i;

    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
        if (arr[i] > largestNumber) {
            largestNumber = arr[i];
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
        if (largestNumber) {
            console.log(largestNumber);
        } else if(arr[i] != largestNumber) {
            sumTotal += arr[i];   
        }
    }
    if (largestNumber === sumTotal) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};

arrayAdditon( myArray );
```

Thanks to JSHint.

Comment: why did you do `sumTotal, i'`?

Comment: To declare loop counter `i` only once at the beginning. Then use it multiple times in for loop