# define variable with braces?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, definition

The book defines javascript variable with braces '{' which returns error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token { " on my compiler (npm 5.6.0)

I found the similar problem here ([SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795000/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-javascript)) which used function inside the variable but I am afraid this is not the right solution.

```
var variable_to_use = from_data(array){

    for(var i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++ )
    {
        for ( var n = 0; n < array.length; n++ ) {
            if ( array[n] > array[n+1]) {
                var temp = array[n];
                array[n] = array[n+1];
                array[n+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return (array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not a very clever solution, but I think it might help if you want to do it.

```
var variable_to_use = function from_data(array) {

    for(var i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++ )
    {
        for ( var n = 0; n < array.length; n++ ) {
            if ( array[n] > array[n+1]) {
                var temp = array[n];
                array[n] = array[n+1];
                array[n+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return (array);
}(array)
```